# GDAL upgrade for MapServer

Tags: gdal, mapserver

Is it possible to upgrade the version of GDAL in MapServer ?
I like to use multiple S3 buckets but according to the documentation this option is available from GDAL 3.5 [(here is the info)](https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html#gdal-configuration-file).

My MapServer version is 7.6.2 running on Debian.

Comment: If you get a newer version of MapServer you'll get a newer version of GDAL too - `apt-get install mapserver`